# Can't return the correct value from a recursive permutation function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I am trying to modify [this blogger's version](http://desple.com/post/118425815657/permutations-with-heaps-algorithm-in-javascript) of Heap's Algorithm.

My issue is that this function prints out every permutation just fine, however if I try to add these permutations to an array which I print out after the function is run, I get the same value for every element in the array.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/og5or1yv/1/) and I've pasted my code below. Does anyone know why I am getting this behavior?

```
// Purpose is to create every permutation from the elements in the array
// We can do this by using Heap's algorithm
var start = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var arr2 = []; // I ADDED THIS LINE
generate(start.length, start);

// Generate the permutation for a given n (amount of elements) and a given array
function generate(n, arr) {
    // If only 1 element, just output the array
    if (n == 1) {
        console.log(arr);
        arr2.push(arr); // I ADDED THIS LINE
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < n; i+= 1) {
        generate(n - 1, arr);

        // If n is even
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            swap(arr, i, n - 1);
        } else {
            swap(arr, 0, n - 1);
        }
    }
}

function swap(arr, idxA, idxB) {
    var tmp = arr[idxA];
    arr[idxA] = arr[idxB];
    arr[idxB] = tmp;
}

console.log(arr2); // I ADDED THIS LINE
```

Comment: `arr2` contains the same array over and over.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for pointing to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript), that solved the issue. I should not have been passing an array to push to another array, but instead a shallow copy of the array (via the slice method) to another array. Thanks.